# Sigar binary make JVM crash on Windows10 & jdk11

Tags: sigar

Hi i'm using `sigar` very usefully,
but some critical problem was occurred.

in `Windows 10` & `jdk11` sigar lib makes JVM crash(append logs below) at all method
but, It works fine when using `jdk8` under same environment.

It seems to my `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` isn't compatible with `jdk11` on `windows 10`.
so i update my `sigar binary` to `1.6.4` download from https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/magelan/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip
Unfortunately problem isn't resolved.
is any resolution about this problem?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=28016, tid=5076
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.6+8) (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: org.ngrinder.NGrinderAgentStarter --mode=agent --command=run -o

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17134 (10.0.17134.753)
Time: Thu Feb 13 18:15:10 2020 ¢¥eCN©öI¡¾©ö C¡ÍA¨ª¨öA elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000219633f8800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=5076, stack(0x000000256b800000,0x000000256b900000)]

Stack: [0x000000256b800000,0x000000256b900000],  sp=0x000000256b8fee50,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.hyperic.sigar.ProcState.gather(Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Sigar;J)V+0
j  org.hyperic.sigar.ProcState.fetch(Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Sigar;J)Lorg/hyperic/sigar/ProcState;+11
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getProcState(J)Lorg/hyperic/sigar/ProcState;+2
j  org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getProcState(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hyperic/sigar/ProcState;+6
j  org.ngrinder.NGrinderAgentStarter.checkDuplicatedRun(Ljava/lang/String;)V+26
j  org.ngrinder.NGrinderAgentStarter.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+227
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000009811d78


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x0000000010014ed4 sigar-amd64-winnt.dll
RAX=0x0000000009811c40 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x000002197fe1ab58} 'gather' '(Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Sigar;J)V' in 'org/hyperic/sigar/ProcState'
RCX=0x00000219633f8b40 points into unknown readable memory: 90 5d 23 16 ff 7f 00 00
RDX=0x000000256b8ff0b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
RSP=0x000000256b8fee50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
RBP=0x000000256b8ff080 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
RSI=0x0000000000200021 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000268 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000032 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000007107f73c0 is an oop: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar 
{0x00000007107f73c0} - klass: 'org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar'
R10=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007fff162b0188 jvm.dll
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x000002197fe1ab48 is pointing into metadata
R14=0x000000256b8ff0b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
R15=0x00000219633f8800 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000009811c40, RBX=0x000002197fe1ab50, RCX=0x00000219633f8b40, RDX=0x000000256b8ff0b0
RSP=0x000000256b8fee50, RBP=0x000000256b8ff080, RSI=0x0000000000200021, RDI=0x0000000000000268
R8 =0x0000000000000032, R9 =0x00000007107f73c0, R10=0x0000000000000010, R11=0x00007fff162b0188
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000002197fe1ab48, R14=0x000000256b8ff0b8, R15=0x00000219633f8800
RIP=0x0000000010014ed4, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000256b8fee50)
0x000000256b8fee50:   00000219633f8b40 000000256b8ff0b0
0x000000256b8fee60:   00000219633f8800 0000000000000000
0x000000256b8fee70:   0000000009811c40 0000000000000000
0x000000256b8fee80:   000000256b8ff0b8 000000001002113b
0x000000256b8fee90:   00000219633f8b40 000000256b8ff0b0
0x000000256b8feea0:   0000000000200021 0000000000000268
0x000000256b8feeb0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000256b8feec0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000256b8feed0:   0000000000000000 000002190875c9b0
0x000000256b8feee0:   00007fff160ce510 000002190860a550
0x000000256b8feef0:   000000037f73c000 00007fff15f009e5
0x000000256b8fef00:   000002197fe1ab50 00000219633f8800
0x000000256b8fef10:   0000000100000004 00007fff00000003
0x000000256b8fef20:   00000219633f9160 0000002800000003
0x000000256b8fef30:   00000219633f8800 000000256b8ff0b8
0x000000256b8fef40:   000002197fe1ab48 00007fff159c880f 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000010014ed4)
0x0000000010014eb4:   7c 24 20 00 75 15 48 8d 15 df 58 04 00 48 8b 4c
0x0000000010014ec4:   24 40 e8 45 00 00 00 33 c0 eb 32 48 8b 44 24 20
0x0000000010014ed4:   83 b8 38 01 00 00 00 74 1f 48 8b 44 24 20 44 8b
0x0000000010014ee4:   80 38 01 00 00 48 8b 54 24 20 48 8b 4c 24 40 e8 

.
.
. (skip)
.
.

Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x00000219633f8b40 points into unknown readable memory: 90 5d 23 16 ff 7f 00 00
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x000000256b8ff0b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x00000219633f8800 is a thread
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x0000000009811c40 is an unknown value
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x0 is NULL
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x000000256b8ff0b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000219633f8800
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x000000001002113b sigar-amd64-winnt.dll


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17134 (10.0.17134.753)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 158 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 16287M (6175M free)
TotalPageFile size 23455M (AvailPageFile size 6527M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 74M, peak: 74M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 355M, peak: 355M

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.6+8-LTS) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.6+8-LTS), built on Dec 11 2019 09:17:57 by "mach5one" with MS VC++ 15.5 (VS2017)

END.
```

Comment: "It seems to my sigar-amd64-winnt.dll isn't compatible with jdk11 on windows 10."  Pretty much true. Sigar is unsupported and increasingly incompatible.  You might try [oshi](https://github.com/oshi/oshi)

Comment: @DanielWiddis thanks for comment. but, is oshi support process kill like `new Sigar().kill(pid, 15);`? It seems not support: https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/277

Comment: OSHI supports command lines.  `if (Platform.isWindows()) { ExecutingCommand.runNative("taskkill " + pid); } else { ExecutingCommand.runNative("kill -15 " + pid); }` should do the trick.

Comment: On Java 9+, `Optional<ProcessHandle> proc = ProcessHandle.of(pid); if (proc.isPresent()) { proc.destroy(); }`